# Привести Object к Cookie

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В БД записал объект класса Cookie вот таким вот образом :

```
public void addUser(String telephone , String name , Cookie cookie) {
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO users (idTelephone , Name , cookie) 
 VALUES ('"+telephone+"','"+name+"', ?);";
        System.out.println(query);
        prepare = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        prepare.setObject(1, cookie);
        prepare.executeUpdate();
        prepare.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Читаю таким образом :

```
public Cookie enter(String telephone , String name) {
    Cookie cookie = null;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT Cookie FROM users WHERE idTelephone 
 ='"+telephone+"' "+" AND Name = '"+name+"';";
        stat = connect.createStatement();
        result = stat.executeQuery(query);
        result.next();
        cookie = (Cookie) result.getObject("Cookie");
        stat.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

Вот где я принимаю куки :

```
ModelFiles model = new ModelFiles((Connection) 
getServletContext().getAttribute("Connection"));
    Cookie cookie = model.enter(telephone , name);
        if(cookie != null) {
            response.addCookie((Cookie)cookie);
            response.sendRedirect("Load.jsp");
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("FailAuthorization.html");
        }
}
```

Выбивает такую ошибку :

> [B cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.Cookie
>       at Models.ModelFiles.enter(ModelFiles.java:145)
>
> cookie = (Cookie) result.getObject("Cookie");

Пробовал проверить на "инстансоф" еще до попытки привести к Cookie

```
if(cookie instanceof Cookie){
   system.out.println("Кастится")
}else{
   system.out.println("Не кастится");
```

Результат :

> Не кастится(то бишь не приводится);

В БД храню cookie в колонке типа Blob вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В БД ОБЪЕКТ ЗАПИСЫВАЕТСЯ!Вот только назад никак не могу забрать)

Comment: Попытался сделать вот так: брать вместо Object  Blob. getBlob() и кастить его - ничего не получается

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Cookie enter(String telephone , String name) {
    Cookie cookie = null;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT Cookie FROM users WHERE idTelephone ='"+telephone+"' "+" AND Name = '"+name+"';";
        stat = connect.createStatement();
        result = stat.executeQuery(query);
        result.next();
        InputStream in = result.getBinaryStream("Cookie");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        cookie = (Cookie)ois.readObject();
        stat.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

Я такой лежу,пытаюсь заснуть и вспомнил про десериализацию объектов!Метод setObject записывает сериализованный объект.И прочитать мне нужно дисериализованный объект!Потом я могу привести Object к Cookie!